# Importing a txt file when number of columns varies?

Tags: r, text-files

I have problems importing a `.txt` file into R because the number columns changes from eight to nine. Initially, my data has eight columns:

```
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Open Interest, Delivery Month
```

Later, I add an additional column `Unadjusted close`. How should I import the data? Somehow the `Unadjusted close` column has to be ignored at the beginning. I've tried

```
data1 <- read.table("AD_0.TXT", sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the `fill` argument in the `read.table` function. Suppose I have the following file

```
"A","B","C"
1,2,3
4,5
6,7,8
```

called `tmp.txt`. Note that row two has only two values. Then

```
> a = read.table("tmp.txt", sep=",", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
> a
  A B  C 
1 1 2  3
2 4 5 NA
3 6 7  8
```

You use then standard sub-setting commands to remove (if you want to), any rows that contain `NA`:

```
> a[!is.na(a$C),]
  A B  C 
1 1 2  3
3 6 7  8
```