# When importing data into R how to make all colums appear in the same row?

Tags: r

When I try to import a text file with over **6000 rows** and **9 colums** the output is showing me **8 columns** in the same row and the 9th is below all others. Furthermore, only the last 500 rows show up in my console only containing the **UnadjClose**. How do I do it right?

I tried: `Dataset<-read.table("AD.TXT",sep=",",header=TRUE)`

File: [Text file to be imported](http://rapidshare.com/files/454173011/AD.TXT)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean.  And how is this question related to / different from your post yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402758/importing-a-txt-file-when-number-of-columns-varies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like R is wrapping what it prints to the console based on width. By default, R wraps at 80 which you can override with `options(width = XXX)` where XXX represents your desired width. `?options` has more information.

To ensure that your dataset was read in properly, I recommend using `str()` which will return the characteristics of your data. Consider the following toy dataset:

```
Dataset <- data.frame(a = rnorm(6000), b = rnorm(6000), c = rnorm(6000)
    , d  = rnorm(6000), e  = rnorm(6000), f  = rnorm(6000), g = rnorm(6000)
    , h =rnorm(6000), i  = rnorm(6000))

> str(Dataset)
(Dataset)
'data.frame':   6000 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ a: num  -0.5784 -0.0951 0.4199 -0.0992 -1.6443 ...
 $ b: num  -2.41 -1.72 0.8 0.57 2.32 ...
 $ c: num  -1.195 -0.661 -1.071 0.449 0.94 ...
 $ d: num  0.114 2.255 0.67 -1.301 -0.792 ...
 $ e: num  0.841 -0.0103 -0.9778 -0.6208 1.0317 ...
 $ f: num  -0.716 -0.803 0.929 -1.967 -0.712 ...
 $ g: num  -1.066 2.407 0.698 1.465 -0.547 ...
 $ h: num  -0.6507 0.1766 -0.0675 0.2491 -0.4547 ...
 $ i: num  0.297 -0.233 -0.479 -0.66 0.214 ...
```

If you want a more visual way to inspect the data, try `edit(Dataset)` or `View(Dataset)`.

Comment: Also useful is `fix()` which is simply a wrapper for `x <- edit(x)`

Comment: `fix()` is a great way to get rid of those pesky outliers that mess up your models ;)

Comment: or, as I like to say: "out, liars"

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that when you print the data after reading it that not everything is printed and that the last column is printed below the others instead of to the right?

For the printing what matters is what R thinks the width of a line is, see `?options` and look at the section on 'width', sometimes this number gets updated automatically, sometimes it does not and you need to do it manually.  The 'max.print' option may also be of interest.  You can also look at the help for the print function you are using (possibly implicitly) to see if there are other options (number of digits, etc.) that you could set to make the print out easier to read.

If you just want to look at the data and have access to all of it then I would suggest using the 'View' function rather than printing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is right. The display on the console is not how it is stored internally. If you really want to change the appearance in the console, you'll have to set the options, eg :

```
op <- options("width"=200) 
      # to determine how many columns are printed on the screen
Dataset
options(op)
```

Better use `edit()` or `View()` as the others suggested, or just open your file in EXCEL. Sorry for the swearing...

Comment: Thank you guys for the answer you helped me a lot. Now i get everything in one row. The only exception is when i try to list the complete dataset that has 541 rows, the data is then a mess below each other and headings are missing for some reason.Some R
consoles automatically change the value when they are
resized, can i do this too?- i am using R on Ubuntu(Linux)

Comment: Furthermore i can't see all rows when i try more then nrows=500

Comment: I tried it with View(Dataset), but the last column is missing completely.

Comment: Every time i open R i have to adjust the width option again because its always restored to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

```
# auto width adjustment
.adjustWidth <- function(...){
      options(width=Sys.getenv("COLUMNS"))
      TRUE
}

.adjustWidthCallBack <- addTaskCallback(.adjustWidth)
```

That's it, finally I have it.